# Add bootstrap pagination dynamic

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I'm looking for a way so that for each 10th post, it add a pagination, so that it's sperating my pages, dynamic. BUt not sur what i should do?.

This is my foreach code:

```
@foreach (var Thread in Model.Threads)
    {
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @Html.ActionLink(Thread.Title, "Post", "Threads", new { @id = Thread.Id }, new { @class = "CategoryTitles" })
            <br /><br /><p style="margin-left: 25px;">By: @Thread.ApplicationUser.UserName</p><hr />
        </div>
    }
```

But don't know what to do from now

Comment: you want to see a predefined number of Thread per page?

Comment: Want it to be that for each 10th page it's adds 1 pagination page, so yeah 10 threads per page.